# Declare an object with darkroom

Tags: jquery, github, javascript

i try to use the lib darkroom. I have clone the git project on github [click here](https://github.com/MattKetmo/darkroomjs)

I have install the lib an run the index.html whitout probleme but i have an error on my console.
On the github on usage, MattKetmo say to declare an new object on darkroom.

```
<script>
    new Darkroom('#target');
</script>
```

I had try to put this declaration on jQuery dom ready and it always doesn't work. Like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {¬
  new Darkroom('#target');¬
 });
```

And in my console my error is "Darkroom is not defined".
I have include all files .css and .js . Like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./build/css/darkroom.min.css">¬
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./demo/css/page.css">¬
<script src="/vendor/fabric.js"></script>¬
<script src="/build/js/darkroom.min.js"></script>¬
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>¬
```

Any person have an idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "And in my console my error is "Darkroom is not defined". I have include all [JS files]." These two statements are in conflict. Are you sure you've linked to the Darkroom JS file properly? Check the scripts page of your dev tools, or open up the page source and click on the link to the JS file to see if its loaded.

Comment: Maybe try `build/js/darkroom.min.js` instead of `/build/js/darkroom.min.js`.

Comment: Yep I'm sure. And i think if I didn't link the js I would have an error in my console.

Comment: I have try your solution doesn't work. :(

Comment: I've just had a look at the demo. Try `./build/js/darkroom.min.js`? And also `./vendor/fabric.js`.

Comment: I had find my problem and is not on darkroom.min.js but it's on darkroom.js

Comment: How you solved this issue? I am starting to use Darkroom. I amgetting the same error after adding this js file

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, I resolved it by including the darkroom.js and fabric.js files in the body of my html document instead of including these files in the head. Don't ask me why but it works when you include the files in the body.